# C# ArgumentNullException was unhandled (SpriteBatch.Draw)

Tags: c#, xna, spritebatch

I am actually a new student in XNA, finding this library very interesting, but I still lack some knowledge to go further as I felt on a issue I can't fix on my own :(

The spriteBatch.Draw() method says my texture is null, however I have loaded it in a Resources.cs class and passed the texture in MainMenu.cs, so I don't really know where the problem resides, if anybody could help me about that I would be very thankful !

Resources.cs

```
    class Resources
{
    public static Texture2D pixel;
    public static Texture2D startButton, loadButton, quitButton;

    public static SpriteFont consoleFont;

    public static void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        pixel = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pixel");
        consoleFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Console");

        // UI Ressources :
        startButton = Content.Load<Texture2D>("UI/StartButton");
        loadButton = Content.Load<Texture2D>("UI/LoadButton");
        quitButton = Content.Load<Texture2D>("UI/QuitButton");
    }
}
```

MainMenu.cs

```
    class MainMenu
{
    // Fields
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

    // Constructors
    public MainMenu()
    {
        this.buttons.Add(new Button(new Vector2(480, 132), 256, 48, Resources.startButton));
        this.buttons.Add(new Button(new Vector2(480, 212), 256, 48, Resources.loadButton));
        this.buttons.Add(new Button(new Vector2(480, 292), 256, 48, Resources.quitButton));
    }

    // Methods

    // Update
    public void Update()
    {
    }

    // Draw
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (Button button in buttons)
        {
            button.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Button.cs

```
    class Button : UIElement
{
    int width, height;
    Texture2D texture;

    public Button()
    {
    }

    public Button(Vector2 b_position, int b_width, int b_height, Texture2D b_texture)
    {
        this.position = b_position;
        this.width = b_width;
        this.height = b_height;
        this.texture = b_texture;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple realy
You just have to know the calling order of functions of `Game1`. First, Game1 constructor is called. That's where you've put `mainMenu = new MainMenu();`. After that go `Initialize`, `Load` and so on. You have to move `mainMenu = new MainMenu();` from Game1 constructor to `Load` function, after the `Resources.LoadContent(Content);`, so the resources can be loaded before they are used in `MainMenu`. Your `Game1.cs` code should look like this:

```
public class GameMain : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    MainMenu mainMenu;

    public GameMain()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        this.IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        Resources.LoadContent(Content);
        mainMenu = new MainMenu();
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        mainMenu.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working !
I didn't know I could do like this, I have been looking a video where the guy declared his menu inside the Game constructor, I see it's not always like that, it's logic when I think about it :D

Comment: @JeanMeier that guy probably didn't have Resources class :D btw, that is a good concept! The (you could make it static) resources class. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

While I do not see your Game class my first assumption is that your never calling the public static void LoadContent(ContentManager Content) method inside your Resources class. Since this function is instantiating your textures perhaps this isn't being called.

Comment: I thought it would add a new message after this one sorry, I've added the Game class above :) !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply !
Indeed I forgot to include the Game class, is this the right way to call the resources ?

```
    public class GameMain : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    MainMenu mainMenu;

    public GameMain()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        this.IsMouseVisible = true;

        mainMenu = new MainMenu();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        Resources.LoadContent(Content);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        mainMenu.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```